# Acessar página diferente do padrão

Tags: php, wordpress

Como faço para acessar uma pagina criada junto com as páginas padrões do wp, como sigle, page, etc...

Exemplo, crio uma pagina chamada exemplos.php e quero acessa-la. Que link devo usar, pois se eu tentar http://localhost/site/exemplos.php dá página não encontrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ***wordpress*** tem um sistema de rotas que te impede de acessar páginas dessa forma.

Você pode acessar esse arquivo criando uma página no painel administrativo e selecionando esse arquivo como um template customizado. Para isso, você precisa adicionar um comentário no início do arquivo com o nome do *template*.

Ao adicionar o comentário e recarregando o página do ***wordpress***, ele vai apresentar o *template* como uma opção de *template* customizado.

```
<?php

// Template Name: Nome do Template.

?>
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo, bem básico, mas to tentando entender a estrutura do worpress. Cara, só mais uma coisa, nessa pagina vou listar dados de uma lista dinamica vinda do bd criado na mesma estrutura de tabelas do wp. Já está funcionando, depois do que vc me passou já está listando.